# Unity (C#) - How to use a particle system with a canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Was wondering how I can let the particle system work with UI objects so that I can see some particle effects when I unlock an item in my game

Anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: And you did not even try to [Google](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6di4jQN_1I) it?

Comment: I did but I thought there might be an easier way and people on this site know most of what I need to know anyway

Answer (score -1):

Did some googling for you, would you like to try this? Let me know how it goes, it's a bit old from May last year, but I think it'll work. These guys go into a lot of detail so be sure to read the thread fully.

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/free-script-particle-systems-in-ui-screen-space-overlay.406862/

Comment: Thanks very much I'll give this a go